# PHP / HTML comments tags

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match

I have several HTML pages with codes that look like this:

```
<!-- ID: 123456 -->
```

What I need is a PHP script that can pull that ID number. I have tried the following:

```
if (preg_match('#^<!--(.*?)-->#i', $output)) {
                echo "A match was found.";
            } else {
                echo array_flip(get_defined_constants(true)['pcre'])[preg_last_error()];
                echo "No match found.";
            }`
```

That always gives "No match found", with no error reported. I have also tried the preg_match_all and the same results. The only thing I have found to work is to create an array based on spaces, but that is very time consuming and waste of processor power.

For reference, I have looked and tried just about every suggestion on these pages:

[Explode string by one or more spaces or tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792950/explode-string-by-one-or-more-spaces-or-tabs)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php

[How to extract html comments and all html contained by node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051485/how-to-extract-html-comments-and-all-html-contained-by-node)

Comment: Maybe this is because `-` is a special symbol and should be escaped?

Comment: How is the ID generated?  Why can't you intercept that?

Comment: Remove the `^` from the pattern. Otherwise, it will match only at the start of the string.

Comment: `$output` is the string with `<!-- ID: 123456 -->` or the ID you want captured? Works here, https://eval.in/437735. Might need `m` modifier if you want the `<!` to be only at the start of each line.

Comment: @u_mulder `-` is not a special symbol, except inside square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

How about try this:

```
<!-- ID: ([\w ]+) -->
```

> This will search for all the literals mentioned in your example, and
>   extract the numeric ID. You can fetch it with the help of numbered
>   group.

PS:Use the escaping.

Comment: Here, only `\w` must be escaped.

Comment: Thanks I have updated it, I was trying the regex in java environment and forgot to remove the escape characters.

Answer (score 1):

To extract informations from structured data (as HTML, XML, Json...) use the correct parser ([DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) to query the DOM tree):

```
$html = <<<'EOD'
<script>var a='<!-- ID: avoid_this --> and that <!-- ID: 666 -->';</script>
blahblah<!-- ID: 123456 -->blahblah
EOD;

$query = '//comment()[starts-with(., " ID: ")]';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

$nodeList = $xp->query($query);

foreach ($nodeList as $node) {
    echo substr($node->textContent, 5, -1);
}
```

Feel free to check the result after with `is_numeric` or a regex. You can register your own php function and include it in the xpath query too: http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.registerphpfunctions.php

Answer (score -1):

First think the HTML file as a Text file because you want to read only some text from the .html file.

**test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is a test HTML page<p>
<!-- ID: 123456 -->
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP script that fetch ID from HTML file**

```
<?php

$fileName = 'test.html';

$content = file_get_contents($fileName);
$start = '<!-- ID:';
$end   = '-->';
function getBetween($content,$start,$end){
    $r = explode($start, $content);

    if (isset($r[1])){

        $r = explode($end, $r[1]);
        return $r[0];

    }
    return '';
}


echo str_replace(' ', '', getBetween($content,$start,$end));


?>
```

Comment: This is a very... original approach :) But it's really far better to use a proper XML/HTML parser as shown by Casimir above.